# How to issue a dragstart event with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an event like this:

```
        $(document).on('dragstart', '#' + gridID + ' tr.rgRow, #' + gridID + ' tr.rgAltRow ', function (ev) {
            console.log(ev);
        });
```

I would like to issue a `dragstart` event, like this:

```
$(".rgRow > td, .rgAltRow > td").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim() === "UTT000000899103";
}).parent().dragstart();
```

`parent()` finds the right `tr`, but `dragstart` is undefined. So, how should I proceed instead?

EDIT:

Based on a comment by A. Wolff I have tried `.parent().trigger('dragstart')` but I get an error. Now I try it like this:

```
    $(document).on('dragstart', '#' + gridID + ' tr.rgRow, #' + gridID + ' tr.rgAltRow ', function (ev) {
        console.log(ev);
        var e = ev.originalEvent;
        e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    });
```

and

```
$(".rgRow > td, .rgAltRow > td").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim() === "UTT000000899103";
}).parent().trigger("dragstart");
```

But I get an error, as `ev.originalEvent.dataTransfer` is `undefined`. So I wonder how should I define the `originalEvent`.

EDIT2:

I have been trying with this code:

```
$(".rgRow > td, .rgAltRow > td").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim() === "UTT000000899103";
}).parent()[0].dispatchEvent(new Event("dragstart"));
```

it returns `true`, but does not run the handler defined in the `.on()`.

EDIT3:

I have managed to call `dispatchEvent()` which will be executed by the handler like this:

```
$(".rgRow > td, .rgAltRow > td").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim() === "UTT000000899103";
}).parent()[0].dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("dragstart", {
    bubbles: true,
    dataTransfer: {}
}));
```

It is executed because of `bubbles: true`. However, the error is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'effectAllowed' of undefined

EDIT4:

Based on A. Wolff's comment I have tried this code:

```
var dragEvent = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents"); dragEvent.initEvent("dragstart", true, true); 
dragEvent = $.extend(dragEvent, {dataTransfer: {effectAllowed: null}}); 
$(".rgRow > td, .rgAltRow > td").filter(function() { return $(this).text().trim() === "UTT000000899103"; }).parent().each(function(){ this.dispatchEvent(dragEvent); });
```

which almost solves the problem. The only missing piece of the puzzle is that I need to call `dataTransfer.setData` inside the handler like this:

```
            e.dataTransfer.setData('text', JSON.stringify(data));
```

where `data` is an initialized JSON.

Comment: `.parent().trigger('dragstart')`?!

Comment: @A.Wolff, I have tried that and I get an error, which I described by editing the question.

Comment: But what is your goal here? Can you provide a concrete sample of what you are looking for?

Comment: @A.Wolff, I have a very complicated page where I have a grid at the left side and an iframe on the right side. The left side contains tickets, the right side contains a grid with workers. If I drag a ticket to a worker, I assign a ticket to the worker. I have a map view, which, if visible, hides the grids and on the map I have markers with tickets and markers with workers. If I click on a ticket and then on a worker, I assign a ticket. This works, but I would like to use the drag events instead.

Comment: I am trying to formulate this problem in the simplest possible terms to avoid unnecessary complications.

Comment: But what is then the purpose of triggering dragstart event? And if you want to get `originalEvent` set, you would need to dispatch dragstart event instead but still i don't see any purpose of it here. Do you want to simulate drag and drop instead?

Comment: @A.Wolff, there is a client-side library which does some visual effects on these events. If I do not use the events, then I have to duplicate the code, which I would prefer to avoid.

Comment: I'd use something like this: `var dragEvent = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
dragEvent.initEvent("dragstart", true, true);
dragEvent = $.extend(dragEvent, {dataTransfer: {effectAllowed: null}});
$(".rgRow > td, .rgAltRow > td").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim() === "UTT000000899103";
}).parent().each(function(){
  this.dispatchEvent(dragEvent);
})`  But i have no idea if it is what you are looking for...   Or maybe simulate mousedown & mousemove?!

Comment: @A.Wolff, that is almost the solution. The only thing missing is that I need a setData, which was not mentioned before in my question, therefore I described the last remaining sub-problem inside an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my problem using this `function`:

```
TT.CustomEvent = function () {
    var me = this;
    var overrideMode = false;
    var customEvents = [];
    this.getEvent = function(type, data) {
        if ((!customEvents[type]) || (overrideMode)) {
            var event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
            event.initEvent(type, true, true);
            event = $.extend(event, {
                dataTransfer: {
                    effectAllowed: null,
                    setData: function (key, value) {
                        if (!event.data) {
                            event.data = {};
                        }
                        event.data[key] = value;
                    },
                    getData: function (key) {
                        if (event.data) {
                            return event.data[key];
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            customEvents[type] = event;
        }
        if (data) {
            customEvents[type].dataTransfer.setData(data.key, data.value);
        }
        return customEvents[type];
    }

    this.dispatchEvent = function (target, event, data) {
        overrideMode = true;
        var currentEvent = me.getEvent(event, data);
        target.each(function () {
            this.dispatchEvent(me.getEvent(event, data));
        });
        overrideMode = false;
    }

};
```

Using this I can call `getEvent`, which returns the last event of a certain type or `dispatchEvent`, which will generate a new `event` of a certain type and will dispatch it. I have a `dragstart` event, which will write an element with key `'text'` and value of a certain JSON into `dataTransfer`, using `setData`. Example usage:

```
                    customEvent.dispatchEvent(woContext, "dragstart");
                    techListWindow.dispatchEvent(selectedTech["Tech Name"], "drop", {key: "text", value: customEvent.getEvent("dragstart").dataTransfer.getData("text")});
                    customEvent.dispatchEvent(woContext, "dragend");
```

where `woContext` is a jquery result, `techListWindow` is inside an `iframe` or a separate tab and has a function like this:

```
function dispatchEvent(target, event, data) {
    customEvent.dispatchEvent($("#techTable .row .tooltip-link").filter(function() {
        return $(this).text().trim() === target.trim(); 
    }).parent(), event, data);
}
```

It works well.